# The `containerd` daemon fails to start due to IO error (and subsequent segfault)

Tags: linux, docker, containerd

Running on Manjaro Linux, kernel 5.13. After system update, `containerd` service fails to start and segfaults after it cannot run garbage collection. Logs are attached [on Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/p9vLbvpd).

After short investigation, I found out that problem is that contained receives IO error when it tries to write to its database (particularly to the file `/var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt/meta.db`). However, this file has no IO problems if I read/write it from terminal (both terminal and containerd were run as root).

Reinstalling `containerd` did not help, as well as manually downloading binary releases of several versions from github and even building release versions from source.

Comment: I think that this is the problem: `FATAL: Module aufs not found in directory /lib/modules/5.13.11-1-MANJARO\\n\"): skip plugin"`

Comment: @digijay I don't think aufs is relevant to this crash. Not to mention nobody should be using it anyway.